# Format a number with separators and display more than two digits after decimal point

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to display a number with 3-digits separators and display five digits after the decimal point at the same time.

```
declare @test float
set @test = 7265342.1234 
select convert(varchar(20),cast(@test as money),1)
```

only returns 7,265,342.12

Comment: use this link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx

Comment: @Rony - `FORMAT` is 2012+. Why don't you do this in your application?

Comment: oh sorry m mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to fetch numbers in exact format (5 digits after decimal) you should use the decimal data type to store numbers. Float is an approximate data type. You should not use this data type when exact numeric behavior like above is required. Also casting decimal value to MONEY or SMALLMONEY won't help as these data types support a precision of up to 4 decimal places only. Following query will solve your requirement:

```
declare @test decimal(38,5)
set @test = 7265342.1234 

DECLARE @CharIndex int = charindex('.', @test)
select replace(convert (varchar(33),cast(LEFT(@test,@CharIndex)as money),1),'.00', '')
+'.' + RIGHT(@test,len(@test) - @CharIndex);
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Works indeed. Thanks.